# UIWebView: Add progress bar inside navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, progress-bar

I am new to iOS development. In `UIWebView`, I want to add progress bar inside navigation bar.

Image:

[image]

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.facebook.com";
[self.navigationController.navigationBar
 setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];

UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop target:self action:@selector(cancelAction:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancel;
self.navigationItem.title =urlAddress;
```

Comment: So, the question is...?

Comment: Perhaps you can refer from this library on GitHub? https://github.com/ninjinkun/NJKWebViewProgress